# Requirements Tracability in VSO?

Tags: code-coverage, azure-devops

We are using Visual Studio Online (VSO) for Defect Management, Test Management and Requirements Management.

Is there any way to generate a report that shows a tracability matrix (test coverage) ?  e.g. what Requirements are not covered by one or more test cases?

Bonus points if we can visually show what phase (iteration etc) that the requirement is being dealt with, so we can plan which phase different tests need to be executed in.

Comment: post your research efforts ! on the question

Comment: I don't really have any research to quote Utility, I have tested adding defects, tests cases, and requirements, and linking them together, but there does not seem to be any sort of reports that show the tracability

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own reporting services report that shows this. All the data is there, you just need to get it out.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647430.aspx

There is a significant amount of product documentation on this subject. A simple web search will also yeald results.